# Fields undefined

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django, so I decided to try the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/).

And then the problem comes: I added some code to polls/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I have four error messages like this:

> Undefined variable from import: CharField models.py /Mysite/polls line 4 PyDev Problem

But the models.Field class is all right.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Don't know if it will help, but Python 3.3 and Aptana Studio 3 are used. I created the project from the command line like it is told in the tutorial and then copied .project and .pydevproject files and changed paths and names there.

UPD:
Everything began to work after I changed Python 3.3 for Python 2.7. Thanks to UnLiMiTeD!

Comment: django 1.4 does not support python 3.3

Comment: Ouch! I should go and try to use python 2.7 then.

Comment: Django 1.5 does have Python 3 support, but it's not fully baked yet. Stick with Python 2.7 + Virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper and you'll be just fine.